# 2 divs with same max-width display different widths

Tags: html, css

The div for the red box and the div for the green and purple boxes are both set to the same max-width of 75rem. I'm stumped on how the red box is displaying a max-width of nearly 1250px when stretched on a wide monitor.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c64j5kdq/2/)

I'm applying this helper class to both divs.

```
.wrapper {
margin: auto;
max-width: 75rem;
}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to be working properly in fiddle

Comment: @Kenny my fiddle is showing me the same result as the attached pic when stretched past 1300px. Red div overhanging by about 25px on each side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add CSS `box-sizing:border-box` to your `.hero` will solve the issue.

What happens

As `.hero` has padding 20px on left and right. Your whole div becomes 75rem + 40px

`box-sizing:border-box` makes sure that padding should be included in width. So your div's actual width will become 75rem - 40px

More on box sizing: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp

Comment: Ahh, that did it. Thanks!